# Oracle APEX Interactive Report Fixed Heading Issue

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an Oracle Apex Interactive Report, which looks like below.

[image]

And the heading attribute is set to "Fixed to None".

[image]

In order to have a sticky heading, I have changed the heading attribute to "Fixed to Region", and given a Maximum Report Height as well.

[image]

But after doing this, I noticed that the width of the headings is not aligned with the table contents anymore, like below. I am not sure if it's caused by the vertical scroll bar that was added.

[image]

Has anyone encountered this before and got a solution for it? Thanks a lot.

Application Express version: 5.0.3

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue in APEX 5.0 when fixing headers to Page or Region and I see it often. The problem only appears when the page is first loaded; after a refresh (e.g. doing a sort, or changing columns, or anything like that) the columns get aligned correctly. I only saw this behaviour in Chrome/Firefox, but not in IE.

Comment: c.f. https://community.oracle.com/thread/4042583 for a possible solution

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I tried to run the report in both IE and chrome without a refresh of the report after the page load. You are right, IE looks fine but chrome doesn't. I also tried the javascript in the above link and it doesn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: Can you update your Q with the exact version of APEX you are on?

Comment: I found a solution for my case. Instead of changing width of the heading based on the width of the body, as suggested in the above link, I did the other way around. I changed the width of body based on the width of the heading, and it fixed my issue.Thanks for your help

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Hey Jeffrey... I created an IR report with the wizard... Now I'm trying to hide the search bar along with the `action` button just like the one on the picture above... I don't see when I can do it... Could you help me do that...

Comment: @WilliamMu Hey Willi.. Please could you read my comment above ?